# Error when developing native camera app for Shield tablet

Tags: android

I am developing a native application on my Nvidia Shield tablet to get camera frame. I download the Shield tutorial and I am using Eclipse.

I get the error:

```
01-09 08:45:35.475: I/art(9536): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-09 08:45:35.559: D/AndroidRuntime(9536): Shutting down VM
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): Process: com.nvidia.NativeCamera, PID: 9536
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android11BufferQueueC1ERKNS_2spINS_19IGraphicBufferAllocEEE" referenced by "/data/app/com.nvidia.NativeCamera-1/lib/arm/libnative_camera2.so"...
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at com.nvidia.NativeCamera.NativeCamera.<clinit>(NativeCamera.java:23)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2518)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-09 08:45:35.560: E/AndroidRuntime(9536): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I don't really understand the reason of that error.

Here is my github :https://github.com/xav12358/nativeCamera

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I review your code, logcat line

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android11BufferQueueC1ERKNS_2spINS_19IGraphicBufferAllocEEE" referenced by "/data/app/com.nvidia.NativeCamera-1/lib/arm/libnative_camera2.so"...
```

say that your libnative_camera2.so should be on lib/arm but on the repo libnative_camera2.so is at /libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera2.so
Try to move libnative_camera2.so to lib/arm/

I hope It Helps !

Comment: I don't think it is because Eclipse don't find the library that it don't work. When Eclipse don't find the library it told me that: 
01-17 18:47:01.204: E/AndroidRuntime(4664): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nvidia.NativeCamera-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nvidia.NativeCamera-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative_camera2.so"

I don't understand why but the project don't find the symbol in the libnative_camera2.so. But when I check in the library the symbol is there..